# XCDYouTubeKit youtube parser unable to run in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, video, youtube

I need a youtube parser to play the youtube videos in iOS SDK.I have downloaded the code from [this link.](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) But I am unable to get the **libXCDYoutubeKit.a** and **XCDYouTubeKit framework** and so if I run the app every time I am getting the issue XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h not found.Am I missing anything in the implementation.Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You must use a workspace.

1. File → New → Workspace…
2. Add your project to the workspace
3. Add the XCDYoutubeKit project to the workspace
4. Drag and drop the *libXCDYouTubeKit.a* file referenced from XCDYouTubeKit → Products → libXCDYouTubeKit.a into the *Link Binary With Libraries* build phase of your app’s target.

These steps will ensure that `#import <XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.h>` will work properly in your project.

Alternatively you can use XCDYoutubeKit with [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) which automates all the steps listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I used lib XCD, it's so good!
I got a issue like you and i fixed it by that:

- i import all files in folder XCDYoutubeKit and change line header import and use them.
- Ex in file: XCDYouTubeClient.h, i change #import  to #import "XCDYouTubeOperation.h", do the same for all file header anh use them.
- Hope it's helpfull for you :)